# When can I safely `wp_set_auth_cookie`?

Tags: login

I've built a small, but working code of logging in an user based on his ID:

```
$user_to_login = get_user_by( 'id', 1 );

// Check if user exists
if( $user_to_login ) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_to_login->ID, False );

    /**
     * Fire up the login process.
     */
    do_action('wp_login', $user_to_login->name, $user_to_login );
}
```

I fire this on `init:10` but I thought to myself "Huh, a lot of plugins actually start here and there might be processes which depend on an user object already.". When exactly is it safe / good to fire this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request is not authenticated by the time it enters `init` you can run your authentication logic if you wish.

If you want to be mindful of other plugins, you could run on `init` with a priority of `0` as an example (or a negative value).

Plugins (may) hook onto `init` at the default priority or a priority above the default and or another hook.

You won't catch all edge cases.

Keep in mind, setting `wp_set_auth_cookie` alone may not be enough.

The alternative is to hook into `plugins_loaded`.

This (`plugins_loaded`) is the earliest at which the method `is_user_logged_in` becomes available.

Internally `is_user_logged_in` looks as follows:

```
   function is_user_logged_in() {
       $user = wp_get_current_user();

       return $user->exists();
   }
```

I explain the mechanics of `wp_get_current_user` below:

The global user object `global $current_user` is first populated before `init`.

Specifically in `wp-settings.php`:

```
/**
 * Fires after the theme is loaded.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );

// Set up current user.
$GLOBALS['wp']->init();

/**
 * Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.
 *
 * Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated. WP continues
 * to load on the {@see 'init'} hook that follows (e.g. widgets), and many plugins instantiate
 * themselves on it for all sorts of reasons (e.g. they need a user, a taxonomy, etc.).
 *
 * If you wish to plug an action once WP is loaded, use the {@see 'wp_loaded'} hook below.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
do_action( 'init' );
```

- `$GLOBALS['wp']->init();` calls `WP::init` which calls `wp_get_current_user` which calls `_wp_get_current_user`.
- `_wp_get_current_user` populates `global $current_user`.
- `_wp_get_current_user` fires the filter `determine_current_user`.

```
function _wp_get_current_user() {

    // ... shortened for brevity

    $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
        return $current_user;
    }

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );

    return $current_user;
}
```

There are two default (core) callbacks that hooked onto `determine_current_user`:

```
add_filter( 'determine_current_user', 'wp_validate_auth_cookie' );
add_filter( 'determine_current_user', 'wp_validate_logged_in_cookie', 20 );
```

This is essentially what validates the validity of the user's authentication and if valid, `determine_current_user` will return a corresponding user ID which finally gets passed to `wp_set_current_user( $user_id )`.

---

Therefore you might be best off hooking onto `plugins_loaded`:

```
function wpse_356655_custom_auth_callback() {

    // ... shortened for brevity

    $user_to_login = '...';

    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_to_login->ID, true );

    // if you want is_user_logged_in to work you should set `wp_set_current_user` explicityly
    wp_set_current_user( $user_to_login->ID );

    do_action('wp_login', $user_to_login->name, $user_to_login );

}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_356655_custom_auth_callback' );
```

You may also wish to look further into the `wp_signon` core function, which may also suit your needs.

## Update #1

In relation to your [comment here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/356655/when-can-i-safely-wp-set-auth-cookie/356659#comment520135_356659)

I cannot say this is the best approach but it is viable.

```
function wpse_356655_custom_auth_callback() {

    // ... shortened for brevity

    $user_to_login = '...';

    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_to_login->ID, true );

    // if you want is_user_logged_in to work you should set `wp_set_current_user` explicityly
    wp_set_current_user( $user_to_login->ID );

    // from within this callback, hook on to `init`
    add_action('init', function() use($user_to_login) {

        do_action('wp_login', $user_to_login->name, $user_to_login );

    });

}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_356655_custom_auth_callback' );
```

Comment: Very, very insightful answer and I cannot stress enough the need for more people like you in the eco-system. Deep understanding of a system allows you to write good code that's considerate of others.

Comment: Also, no, `wp_signon` doesn't cut it, because that's just a function to actually sign an user in **with a password provided as well.** It calls `wp_set_auth_cookie` is called. So far, in my testing, it hasn't failed.

Comment: No worries, glad it was helpful. Re: `wp_signon` that is correct, not the suitable function in all cases, but sometimes - if working with credentials. That said, custom auth as per your method is equally fine.

Comment: I discovered a sutle issue with hooking into `plugins_loaded`. The problem is that plugins that hook into `wp_login` or any other hooks provided by the 2 functions we use inside ours...**don't have a chance to do so, unless they fire before `plugins_loaded`. Does it make sense? We fire `wp_login` before anyone had a chance to hook in.

Comment: @DanielM Yeah it makes sense. The question is, at what point do you want to make `wp_login` available? If we take a leaf from what other large plugins like WooCommerce and Easy Digital Downloads do (for example) — they utilise `wp_loaded` and `init` respectively. Take WooCommerce `WC_Form_Handler::process_login`, this method calls `wp_signon` which internally will eventually fire the `wp_login` hook BUT at this point WooCommerce choose to process `WC_Form_Handler::process_login` on the `wp_loaded` hook, which comes after `init`. See my update for a possible solution.

Comment: After giving this some further consideration and albeit without knowing your precise use-case, I tend to think using `init` with a priority of 10 or later and/or a hook later than `init` such as `wp_loaded` is fine. By the time you arrive in your logic the user will either be authenticated-or-not. If not, you authenticate the user and fire `wp_login`. If you do this late in the request flow, other plugins should have  hooked into their respective hooks prior to you firing `wp_login` which means plugins and co' will act upon the firing of the hook.